# Parsing SIP message body

Tags: c, sip, voip

I'm implementing SIP protocol and I'm stuck while parsing SIP message. I'm using the oSIP library. My code is like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <osip2/osip.h>
#include <osipparser2/osip_parser.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
  int i,error;
  osip_message_t *message;
  char text[]="INVITE sip:jarsku@feanor.pc.lut.fi SIP/2.0\nCall-ID: 123456789@aradan\nVia: SIP/2.0/UDP 157.24.25.137:5060\nFrom: Arto <sip:athamala@feanor.pc.lut.fi>\nTo: Jari <sip:jarsku@feanor.pc.lut.fi>\nCSeq: 1 INVITE\nContent-Type: application/sdp\n\nv=0\na=3333aaa333";
  char *p=(char *)&text;

  i = strlen(text);
  error = osip_init(&message);
  error = osip_message_init(&message);
  error = osip_message_parse(message, p, i);
}
```

When I run this code, the message structure is filled with data from text. Respective the fields `call_id, content_lenght, content_type, cseq, from, req_uri, sip_method, sip_version,` to and vias are filled correctly, but in the field message is value 0x0, `message_length` is 0 and message_property is 2.
Error codes are 0 for all three commands.
Why is the message body not parsed ? I'm confused of this things:
In RFC is stated, that every line should be ended with CLRF sequence, but I'm simply using `\n` and it seems like working.
Next I dont like this statement:

```
error = osip_init(&message);
error = osip_message_init(&message);
```

For me, is this weird. In the [documentation of oSIP](http://www.gnu.org/software/osip/doc/html/group__howto2__parser.html) is stated that sequence of:

```
osip_message_t *sip;
osip_message_init(&sip);
osip_message_parse(sip, buffer, length_of_buffer);
osip_message_free(sip);
```

should be enough (in my code I'm using init and message_init), but this is throwing me a Segmentation fault.

And why is possible,  that the field `content_length` is autofilled but the message is not parsed ?

Last question : why is this topic so terribly covered on Internet ? No manuals, oSIP documentation is bad

Thank you

Comment: Side note: You can simple write `char *p = text;`

Comment: What is the status of oSIP library ? It looks like author is using this in his next project eXosip, but i think he dont publish new patches... And is this developer mailing list ? [link](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/osip-dev/2006-11/index.html#00575)

Comment: And when I delete the line error = osip_init(&message) I'm getting return value -5 from osip_message_parse. I can't find what this error code means. I can parse only the start line of that message and when I add some next parameters it fails. Looks like there is some order that I have to keep but i tested it and sometimes it just parses well, even in random order.

Comment: I have no idea what osip is. Also, if that mailing list ever used to be of any use to any one, it is now completely a placeholder for spam messages.

Comment: oSIP - opensource SIP.http://www.gnu.org/software/osip/doc/html/

Comment: Yea, that's what i need to consider. I can't use GPL licensed product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be reading the documentation wrong. The function osip_init() wants a osip_t **osip not a message. Re: [http://www.gnu.org/software/osip/doc/html/group_*howto0*_initialize.html](http://www.gnu.org/software/osip/doc/html/group__howto0__initialize.html)

Comment: Thanks for saving me too! I've been getting segfaults until I did this after `osip_message_init()` and before `osip_message_parse()`. See here: https://github.com/SentryPeer/SentryPeer/commit/65f7bf8f07ef8f9fb46826ee9222a84f33c25c4c#diff-e28974f1b886b2dd273a56232f14b55bdfbbed415975b2fa1b126becf822189f

Answer (score 2):

osip_init is not needed to use just the parser, but you should init the parser with parser_init(); instead.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error as Matka mentioned in his comment.

> return value -5 from osip_message_parse

It was due to a malformed sip message that I was passing to the program while debugging.